# Menu Button Assistance

Tags: html, css, menu, photoshop, slice

Based on this menu structure:

[menu system](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/59d5e4e505.png)

I want to purely use a CSS based Menu System but am unsure what is the best way to approach to get the blue gel 2D button look based on "Home" and "About Us" ?

I basically would like to know how to achieve this button look and then in CSS use this background button and then be able to add the label via html/css.

Is this possible?

Any example tutorials to achieve this would be much appreciated. I also have access to Photoshop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's a multi-part answer:

The button design you speak of is done in the graphic itself (so if you want to get really technical, it's not entirely PURE css)  An example of how to make the "jeweled glossy look" is here:  http://iris-design.info/photoshop/web-20-style-buttons/  It can be easily adapted to get the look you desire.  Note also that there are several sites out there that will create a jeweled web 2.0 like button (I hate that term!) without photoshop.  Just google "web 2.0 button generator"

To make things easier, I'm going to assume that you're using nested

tags to make the menu happen.  Simply set the background of the appropriate list item to your image, with no-repeat, and set height and width to be the correct size to fit the image itself.  Voila, images in the background instead of the css styled background it currently has.

An improvement would be using sprites to speed loading and decrease response time.  See here for more information:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/

Ok, now, all that being said, a TON of people have attacked this issue head on, and there are some really elegant solutions out there that are essentially done for you.  Consider looking around on sites like Smashing, etc for ready-made solutions to help.  Personally, I'm a big fan of supersucker and the suckerfish-type menus that Jquery brings to the table.  Whether or not you want to go that route is of course personal preference.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your response. Just on your method of setting background image to li tag, how would I then add any text label I like that isn't part of the graphic button - sorry for the basic question? With regards to elegant solutions out there already, are you able to point me to one or what to exactly search on. Thanks again.